# Как в JS цикле отправлять Ajax-запросы с интервалом?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Есть код, который проходит по элементам массива и для каждого вызывает Ajax-запрос (jQuery метод `$.ajax(...)`) к скрипту на сервере. Запросы выполняются к серверу одновременно, и по своим причинам он не справляется и выдаёт правильный ответ через раз. Если выполнять те же самые запросы синхронно, друг за другом, (`$.ajax({async: false, ...})`), то все ответы приходят верными. Но так замораживается страница, на которой выполняются все эти запросы. Хотелось бы, чтобы это работало в фоне и плавно подгружало данные на страницу.

Можно ли как-то искусственно установить задержку между вызовами асинхронных Ajax-запросов в JavaScript? Бегло пробежался по статье по промисам и async/await на learn.javascript.ru, но не смог понять, как быстро и красиво добиться желаемого. Заранее спасибо! Код выглядит следующим образом:

```
['Раз', 'Два', 'Три').forEach((item) => {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'script.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { 'name' : item },
        success: (result) => {
            // Сделать что-то
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
doChainedAjaxForArray(arr, index) {
  if (index < 0 || index >= arr.length)
    return;

  $.ajax({
    url: 'script.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { 'name' : arr[index] },
    success: (result) => {
      doChainedAjaxForArray(arr, index + 1);
      // Сделать что-то
    }
  });
}

doChainedAjaxForArray(['Раз', 'Два', 'Три'], 0);
```

Comment: Благодарю, то, что нужно! Оказалось решается простой рекурсией и без использования промисов)